# Will I Lose Completed Mission Progress When Mass Retreating?

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

If I mass-retreat after completing a secondary mission, do I lose any progress from that mission? The popup isn't clear...

Answer (score 4):

No, you will not lose mission progress once you **complete** the mission.

(I did this after one of the story missions, though I'm sure this would work for secondary missions too)

Comment: This holds for all missions.